# Use Legacy Swift Language Version

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, cocoapods, ios10

I am using Swift libraries in Objective-C Project with CocoaPods.

I tried running them in the recently released Xcode 8 GM and I am getting the following error:

[image]

I tried all the solutions in the below link and also from other SO Answers but nothing seems to work.

http://www.ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/xcode/quick-tip-fix-use-legacy-swift-issue-in-xcode-8-beta-3/

Libraries I am using are Charts and XLPagerStrip.

Comment: have you try with swift version 2.3 ?

Comment: I *think* that's a cocopods issue, I have a small framework and I cannot publish another version of because of that exact same error (except I get on the console of course).

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your "Pods" project. For each Pod, choose the target and set it to use the legacy compiler. Note that if you do a "pod install" later, the workspace that gets generated will overwrite the legacy compiler settings, so you have to redo them.